# Can't reset colours after RICH formatting

Tags: python

I have a problem with the rich library.
After installing it, I wrote in the code:

```
from rich import print

d = {
    "employee1": "telephone: 123-456-789 -",
    "employee2": "telephone: 098-654-321",
}
# and in the line with the code I set the color magenta bold:
print(
    d.get(p, "[bold magenta] there is no such employee [/ bold magenta]!")
)
```

The problem is following. After the first attempt to change the color, the color of the text "there is no such employee" wasn't changed but the color of the telephone number changed. Then I removed the color formatting line, but still the phone number has magenta color.

Now, if change the text "there is no such employee" to red color, it change but the phone number is still in magenta.

Even when i remove text formatting and leave only `from rich import print` i still got the phone number in magenta.

Comment: Are you running this on the command line? Have you tried starting a new terminal?

Comment: You should probably end formatting without a space after the slash, and possibly even use the slash twice, e.g. "[/bold /magenta]". Alternatively, just use "[/]" to end all formatting.

Comment: im editing code in IDLE and running it in cmd. Every time i made some changes in code i run it in new cmd.

Comment: "You should probably end formatting without a space after the slash, and possibly even use the slash twice, e.g. "[/bold /magenta]". Alternatively, just use "[/]" to end all formatting."       But why phone number color is change when i didn't change it ?

Comment: Numbers seem to be colored by default. I am getting blue numbers what ever I print. However with your code (just added a loop for assigning something to p) it prints phonenumbers blue with white text and the error message is red.

Comment: Ok so how can i reset color of numbers ?

Answer (score 3):

As said in 'O O's answer, this might be a default setting. I fiddled around a bit
and was able to remove coloring for phone numbers etc. Those are colored by default.
If I run the code below I get the phone numbers in white and the line
'there is no such employee' in magenta.

```py
from rich import print
from rich.console import Console

con = Console(highlight=False)

d = {
    "employee1": "telephone: 123-456-789",
    "employee2": "telephone: 098-654-321",
}

for x in range(0,4):
    p = f"employee{x}"
    con.print(
      d.get(p, "[bold magenta]There is no such employee [/ bold magenta]!")
    )
```

Comment: glad, I could help. Same for you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a default setting. Have a look at https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/highlighting.html .

To quote from the top of that page:

> Rich can apply styles to patterns in text which you print() or log().
> With the default settings, Rich will highlight things such as numbers,
> strings, collections, booleans, None, and a few more exotic patterns
> such as file paths, URLs and UUIDs.
>
> You can disable highlighting either by setting highlight=False on
> print() or log(), or by setting highlight=False on the Console
> constructor which disables it everywhere.

Comment: how can i do that?Where i should write code to reset color of numbers? Im learning Python only 4 days and i dont know how to do it :/

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to have the print on the same line and the to have the colour change you need to put the magenta next toit, try this:

```
print(d.get(p, "[bold magenta]there is no such employee[/bold magenta]!"))
```

Comment: I did it for the first time and after that color was changed but on the phone number :/

Comment: The print does not need to be in one line. Also the space does not mess it up for me